# Using FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions Flags for Custom Control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Upon browsing the source code for WPF I stumbled across a few dependency properties that use certain FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions in their definitions. I am creating a custom window control with its own template design. One of the dependency properties I am creating is to set the background color of the title bar:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleBarBackgroundProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "TitleBarBackground",
        typeof(Brush),
        _typeofThis,
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
            null,
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender |
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.SubPropertiesDoNotAffectRender));
```

I'm trying to understand if `FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.SubPropertiesDoNotAffectRender` is good to have for my property. I am setting these two flags because this is how a Panel's background dependency property is defined [here](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/blob/6634719e22053aab8e5e0db37618170494aea334/src/Microsoft.DotNet.Wpf/src/PresentationFramework/System/Windows/Controls/Panel.cs#L140).

I found the following article on Microsoft's learn: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkpropertymetadataoptions?view=windowsdesktop-7.0

My question is what qualifies as a "sub-property" and do I need it for my property I am defining if all I'm doing with it is binding it to a Grid's background property (which I assume already has these flags since it inherits the panel's background property). Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you need any FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions at all? AffectsRender means that the OnRender method is called each time the property value changes. Is that what you need? You should provide more details of your problem.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out if I need that. This property is binded to a Grid element's background property in a template for my custom window control. Does that make sense? The background color updates when the property is changed, I'm just trying to figure out if these flags are giving some sort of optimization.

Comment: You certainly do not need those flags. Try whether your control does what you expect without the flags, then don't set any FrameworkPropertyMetadata at all, since `null` is already the default value of a property of type Brush. Also use `nameof(TitleBarBackground)`.

Comment: Ah you're right, I'll do that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the property only serves as source property of a Binding there is no need to set any property metadata at all. If re-rendering is required, the target object of the Binding should initiate it.

The declaration of the dependency property identifier field should simply look like this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleBarBackgroundProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(TitleBarBackground),
        typeof(Brush),
        typeof(YourControl));
```

Comment: Makes the most sense, thank you for the clarification.

Comment: A bit related to this question but as I was going through my other properties removing the unnecessary flags, I wanted to know if I need to use [TypeConverter(typeof(LengthConverter))] above my height/width (get/set) properties, which also are only used to bind to my custom window template

Comment: Take a look at the LengthConverter documentation. If you don't need conversion from non-standard strings representing a double value in XAML, it is not necessary to set the TypeConverter attribute.